# Only one connection to a remote api or each component its own connection

Tags: java

I have created an api that connects to another outside api. Now i am not sure how to design my way of connections within my project. What is the better way one connection or each class each own connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One connection manager with api usable from your classes would probably be best. By implementing as a service for other classes, it keeps all the code for connections in one place where it can be modified once instead of all over the place. Also, it us usually a good rule to keep your objects to a single purpose so each can do what it needs to do and then aggregate simple objects into components and services.